# Will my android service drain the entire battery?

Tags: android

I am from Argentina, sorry for my bad english...

I am doing an android app and i have one service.

This service send a notification to a external webservice every XX seconds (XX is a parameter set by the user)

So i have:

XX seconds = ReminderTime;

```
for(;;){
    try {
    if(chkReminderNotif == true)
    {
        if(ReminderCount >= ReminderTime) {
            ReminderCount = 0;
            SendDataService("...........");
        }
        else{
            ReminderCount = ReminderCount + 1;
        }
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

There is best way to do this?

I will drain the battery with this code?

Without taking into account the consumption of part SendDataService("...........");"

Thanks and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: *I will drain the battery with this code?* yes

Comment: It would already be a lot better if you did `Thread.sleep(ReminderTime * 1000L)` instead of waking up the thread every second.

Comment: Thanks Tim Castelijns!

Comment: @Henry Thanks... The problem is when the user change the ReminderTime parameter... If ReminderTime was 600 (10 minutes), and the user change ReminderTime to 5 seconds, the thread still sleep for 600 seconds, and then change to new value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will drain your battery.

You want to use the Android's job scheduler API instead. Here is a good introduction to it.

https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129

Comment: Thanks you, i will investigate JobsSheduler!

Comment: Hello... If i using JobsSheduler, when screen off, the job only work every one minute aprox... I want loop every XX seconds (10 seconds, 15, 5 etc..)